# Is it possible to add a scroll for a table inside a responsive parent? (without specified width)

Tags: css

I have a grid template. It is responsive and centered in the middle.

If the table overflows the `div#content` width I want to add a scroll, so the table won't make the content div wider.

The default way of doing it by wrapping the table in a container with `overflow-x: scroll;` doesn't work because there is no set width of `div#content`, instead the table expands the `div#content`.

```css
#table_container {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
table {
  width: max-content;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
div#content {
  grid-area: Article;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#wrap {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: min-content 1fr;
  gap: 20px 20px;
  grid-template-areas:
  "Article-header Article-header" 
  "Nav      Article" 
  ".        Comments";
}
main nav {
  grid-area: Nav;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  <main>
    <nav>nav</nav>
    <div id="content">
        post
        <div id="table_container">
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td>12345</td>
              <td>12345</td>
              <td>12345</td>
              <td>12345</td>
              <td>12345</td>
              <td>12345</td>
              <td>12345</td>
              <td>12345</td>
              <td>12345</td>
              <td>12345</td>
              <td>12345</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: I currently made it with JS by putting the table in iframe, but still waiting for a better solution